# Can i use LUIS Bot for intranet web application to create data

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have created a LUIS application with below steps

step 1: I have created a LUIs web app bot in azure portal,
step 2: enabled the channel for Direct link
step 3: calling the bot api from my web app (hosten in my iis localhost url)

Now when i type from the chat window from my application, the trigger is happening in the azure web app. But i need to create some data in my localhost web app through REST api/SQL. How can i perform this?

Is there any possibility thata LUIS web app bot can also run in locally and consumed by localhost or is there any otherway to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this sample, [01.browser-echo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_es6/01.browser-echo), from the Botbuilder-Samples repo. It's just an echo bot, so you'll need to update to your code, however the bot is fully contained within the web chat. It does not rely on Azure services or direct line to run, but instead makes use of a custom WebChatAdapter.

Using this setup, you should be able to run the bot completely locally or within a closed network environment. The latter will depend on what you are trying to do, of course (i.e. making API calls, etc.). It is written in Javascript, but makes for a great option.

Hope of help!

Comment: Hi, Steven Sounds like good solution, but the link you shared is not working. it gives me 404 page not found error. could you please provide the unbroken link which would be helpful

Comment: @Mathiyazhagan Updated link to reflect the correct address.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go through this - [Deploying bot to personal server](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3087) Microsoft/BotBuilder thread. You will find that [Is developing bots using Microsoft Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://thewebspark.com/2018/04/15/is-microsoft-bot-framework-without-azure-possible/).

> You can develop the bot over local machine also using the Bot Builder
>   SDK and testing the bot service using the bot emulator running on
>   localhost.

**References:**
[How can I host the .Net Bot application On- premises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358381/how-can-i-host-the-net-bot-application-on-premises)
[Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Comment: Thanks Niranjan, I tried this but it works good with bot emulator. But without azure how can i enable web chat or direct link chat for my onprim hosten bot service? do you have any idea plz suggest